# How exactly does submitting an interdisciplinary NSF fellowship proposal affect your chances at winning it?

Tags: funding, nsf

I've received differing answers from many people on this. I'm proposing a planetary atmospheres project and while I'm submitting it to Geosciences - Climate Dynamics, I'll also probably include "Physics and Astronomy - Astronomy" and "Physics and Astronomy - Theoretical Physics" as part of the "% of program for Primary Field of Study". I'm in a geoscience department, but my adviser is a theoretical physicist and I come from an Astrophysics background. I'm slightly hesitant about including panels beyond geoscience though, since the physics/astronomy applicant pool is *far* stronger than the geoscience applicant pool, and there may be much bigger expectations expected from people in physics/astronomy.

One person told me that they might just average the scores of the reviews from both panels, while someone else told me that it can't hurt at all.

> *Is your proposed graduate program interdisciplinary?*
>
> Note: Interdisciplinary research is defined as a mode of research by
>   teams or individuals that integrates information, data, techniques,
>   tools, perspectives, concepts, and/or theories from two or more
>   disciplines or bodies of specialized knowledge to advance fundamental
>   understanding or to solve problems whose solutions are beyond the
>   scope of a single discipline or area of research practice. Please
>   provide an estimate of the balance among the Fields of Study
>   represented.

Comment: I read your title, and thought: “100% of those who didn't submit an interdisciplinary proposal don’t win it”

Comment: Do you mean a proposal for an NSF _fellowship_, or a regular grant?

Comment: **Do not listen to the Impostor Syndrome!**

Comment: In response to F'x, it's not true that 100% of recipients are interdisciplinary. The NSF is big about "broader impacts" and "intellectual merit," and I suspect that being interdisciplinary lends itself very nicely to having "broader impacts."

Comment: @mixedmath what I meant is “100% of those who have an interdisciplinary proposal and don't submit it don't win” :)

Comment: Aha - a truer statement has never been said.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [NFS](http://www.nsfgrfp.org/how_to_apply/choosing_a_primary_field)

> Your application will be assigned to the field of study you list first
>   in the Proposed Graduate Program section. ...
>   Therefore, you should choose which field you list first carefully,
>   with consideration of which panel has the most appropriate component
>   fields. ... All interdisciplinary applications are clearly marked as such during
>   the review process. Many panelists have interdisciplinary expertise
>   and are capable of evaluating interdisciplinary applications.
>   Additionally, if necessary, the panel can transfer your application to
>   another panel for either a full review or for commentary and feedback.

While in some cases they might average the scores, this does not appear to be a requirement. I would suspect that in most cases they would do the review within a single panel and rate you accordingly and only seek expertise outside the panel if absolutely necessary.